# JS allow single and double quotes to print

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing issues with single and double quotes inside the string. In my case,it is:

```
var Des = "It's alright. We are the so-called "Vikings" from the north.";
```

I want to show this string as it is. I have a random string. Sometime, its only single quote, double quote, and sometime nothing.

Code i tried so far is:

```
var fieldData  = "<input type='text' name='desc' value='\""+Desc+"\"'>";
```

But its not working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first escape the double quotes within the `Des` string using `\"`.

Then you need to HTML encode the `value` attribute so that the quotes within the string do not interfere with the quotes delimiting the attributes themselves. As you've tagged jQuery you can do this very simply by using `val()`, as that encodes the values for you. Try this:

```js
var Des = "It's alright. We are the so-called \"Vikings\" from the north.";
var $input = $('<input type="text" name="desc">').val(Des);
$input.appendTo('body');
```

```css
/* only used here to make the output fully visible without scrolling */
input { width: 325px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have a dynamic string. i need to replace " with \" from the whole string

Comment: But i am not able to convert the single quote with '\ and double quote with "\ . :(